# How can I delete a keychain password for github and vscode?

Tags: macos, password, keychain, big-sur, git

The way of deleting keychain access codes is to open the keychain access control and right click on the code and delete which worked before .

[image]

But Now It doesn't and when I press delete nothing happens .

How can I force delete any keychain access ? Is there a way by doing this with terminal ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting from the Safari passwords page? It should have the same effect

Comment: @EzekielElin It's not related to safari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem by doing these commands in terminal :

> $ git credential-osxkeychain erase <kbd>return</kbd>
>
> host=github.com <kbd>return</kbd>
>
> protocol=https <kbd>return</kbd>
>
> <kbd>return</kbd>
>
> <kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: The important thing that isn't obvious here is that the ⏎ symbol represents hitting "enter" and that the trailing two are required. I tried several variations on this and it didn't work until I hit enter each time.